# Symmetric Difference javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this freecodecamp algorithm question where I had to collect the difference of two or more arrays. I used map to get the difference of array but the problem is I only get two elements;

```
function sym(args) {
  args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  var newArr = args.map(function(el, index, arr){
    console.log(arr.indexOf(arr[index]));

    if(arr.indexOf(arr[index] === -1 )){
    //  console.log(arr[index]);
      return args.push(arr[index]);
    }
  });

return newArr; // my newArr returns [3, 4] instead of [3,4,5]

}

console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]));

//sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]) should return [3, 4, 5]
//sym([3, 3, 3, 2, 5], [2, 1, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 9, 8], [1]) should return [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `arr.indexOf(arr[index])` doesn't make much sense to me ;)

Comment: @georg `arr.indexOf(arr[index] === -1)` makes even less sense.

Comment: okay thanks for spotting that;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your function is a little more complex than only selecting the unique values, cause you want to filter them out... and also accept multiple arrays. This should work.

```js
var sym = (...arrays)=>{
    //Concat Items
    const allItems = arrays.reduce((a,c)=>a.concat(c), []);
    // Identify repeated items
    const repeatedItems = allItems.filter((v,i,a)=>a.indexOf(v) !== i);
    // Filter repeated items out
    const diff = allItems.filter(item=>repeatedItems.indexOf(item) < 0);
    console.log(diff);
};

sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]); // [3,5,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we could do also this way since we want them to be ordered at the end.

For more detail about the original problem please consult this link: [FreecodeCamp Link: Symmetric Difference](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/coding-interview-prep/algorithms/find-the-symmetric-difference)

```js
const sym = (...args) => {
  // Merge all the different arrays and remove duplicate elements it means elements that are present both on two related arrays
  let tab = args.reduce((a, b) => [
    ...a.filter(i => !b.includes(i)),
    ...b.filter(j => !a.includes(j))
  ], []);
  // Then remove the rest of duplicated values and sort the obtained array
  return Array.from(new Set(tab)).sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

console.log(sym([1, 2, 3, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4])); // [3, 4, 5]
console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5])); // [1, 4, 5]
console.log(sym([3, 3, 3, 2, 5], [2, 1, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 9, 8], [1])); // [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The **Set** data structure is used here to remove duplicated values thanks to its characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach will work; you're supposed to create an array with elementos from both arrays, so a single `.map` won't do the job. Filtering through both arrays should work, although it will probably leave enough room for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

> my newArr returns [3, 4] instead of [3,4,5]

You are using `map` which will only return one value per iteration (which is why you are getting only 2 values) and in your case **you are checking if the index is found or not** (not the item)

You need to concatenate all the arrays and then remove those which are repeated

**Concatenate**

```
var newArr = args.reduce( ( a, c ) => a.concat( c ) , []);
```

**Create a map** by number of occurrences

```
var map = newArr.reduce( (a,c) => ( a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a ) , {});
```

Iterate and filter through those keys whose value is 1

```
var output = Object.keys( map ).filter( s => map[s] === 1 ).map( Number );
```

**Demo**

```js
function sym(args) 
{
    args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var newArr = args.reduce( ( a, c ) => a.concat( c ) , []);
    var map = newArr.reduce( (a,c) => ( a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a ) , {});
    return Object.keys( map ).filter( s => map[s] === 1 ).map( Number );
}

console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an Object for counting the items and return only the items which have a count.

```js
function sym(array) {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => {
        var count = {};
        a.forEach(v => count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1);
        b.forEach(v => count[v] = (count[v] || 0) - 1);
        return Object.keys(count).map(Number).filter(k => count[k]);
    });
}

console.log(sym([[3, 3, 3, 2, 5], [2, 1, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 9, 8], [1]]));
```